# Manifest.mf cannot find org.junit

Tags: maven, junit, tycho

I'm trying to run jUnit tests for an Eclipse RCP application with Tycho.

For that I created a simple jUnit test, that runs when I click on Run as > jUnit-Test. But when I want to run it with mvn test, it doesn't find jUnit.

I read in the Internet that I have to add jUnit to the Build-Path. -> I already did that. Furthermore I read that I have to add jUnit as a require-bundle in my Manifest.mf file. But there is the problem!! I get the error: Bundle 'org.junit' canot be resolved.

My MANIFEST.MF file looks like this:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Tests
    Bundle-SymbolicName: myPackageName
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
    Bundle-Vendor: myCompany
    Fragment-Host: thePackageWhereTestesPluginIs
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
    Require-Bundle: org.junit
```

Where is my mistake? When I take org.junit4 it cannot be resolved either...

Thank you!

Update:

Now I use instead of require-bundle:

```
    Import-package: org.junit4
```

(or org.junit, its' behavior is the same) and it can be resolved in the manifest.mf file. But when I run it, I get the following error:
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle myTestBundle cannot be resolved
Resolution errors:
   Bundle myTestBundle - Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.junit4; version="0.0.0"

How can I solve this?

Thank you!!

My pom file of the test bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
        <artifactId>myProject.tycho.master</artifactId>
        <groupId>myProject</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../myProject.tycho.master/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject.myTestBundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The parent pom:

```
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myProject</groupId>
<artifactId>myProject.tycho.master</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho.version>0.17.0</tycho.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>../myProject.myTestBundle</module>

</modules>



<repositories>
    <!-- configure p2 repository to resolve against -->
    <repository>
        <id>Repository1</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>url-to-a-p2-site-on-my-server</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resolver>p2</resolver>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                <target>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myGroupId.target</artifactId>
                        <classifier>targetPlatform</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </target>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>macosx</os>
                        <ws>cocoa</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <ignoreTychoRepositories>false</ignoreTychoRepositories>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    </project>
```

Update:
I think I resolved the problem!
I added jUnit to my p2 Update sites and now I don't get any errors!

Comment: Can you post the pom file, cause i assume you missed to add the junit dependency in your pom file.

Comment: Tycho should print out better error messages: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405790

Comment: IsaMunich, welcome to stackoverflow. It seems that you have found the solution to you question. In this case, you should answer your own question and accept that answer. This is so that others know that they don't need to provide further answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding jUnit as a p2 Update site and used it in the Manifest.mf as:

```
Require-Bundle: org.junit; bundle-version = "4.11.0"
```